# Error 500 and WSOD after restoring backup

Tags: backups

Good morning to all. 
I'm totally new to Drupal and I'm sure this is a newbie question but...I'm stuck in a error 500 after restoring a database backup.
Here are the steps I have done:

- Install *backup and migrate* plugin in the production site
- Create and download a complete backup
- Install Drupal 7 on my local machine
- Create a drupaldb on mysql
- Go to localhost/install.php and follow the wizard creating the same user I have in the production website
- Activate the corporate theme
- Activate all the plugins I need as the production website

Until here the website works perfectly. I can create content and translate it and see it normally.

- Import the backup in my local installation using the same plugin.

And here the website breaks
I can access to localhost/es/user and see the login form, but I cannot login. i can switch to localhost/en/user and see the page rendered in english but I cannot login either.

Submitting the login form or trying to access to any other page in any kind of browser (tested with Firefox and Chrome) give me ERROR 500.
Nothing appears in apache error.log

I have repeated several times the process, even reinstalling apache but nothing works.
I double checked my files permissions (777 locally), and the apache, mysql and drupal versions (the are all the same in both environments)

I tried even with a manual backup of the mysql DB but nothing...

It seems obvious is something related to the content I import but I cannot discover what is because in the apache2/error.log nothing is written.

Any suggestion? Thank you

**UPDATE**

As I don't have yet enough reputation to answer directly in the comments I have to update my question.

- My settings.php point to the right db (and the user has all the permissions)
- The website is not a subdirectory
- If I copy manually the contents pof a page (in the 2 languages) it works perfectly, so I suppose in not matter of a .htaccess misconfiguration
- I tried (as suggested here) the opposite import flow too: follow the wizard, restore the db without enabling any module and.. it didn't worked. (enabling only B&M neither)

The only interesting thing I noticed until now is when I write `localhost` I'm redirect to `localhost*/es`.

And more, If I write `localhost/es/?q=node/80` the url is rewritten correctly with the most friendly url `localhost/es/productname` but the page still gives error 500 and nothing is rendered.

**SECOND UPDATE**

I have created a virtual machine with vmware to build a new environment, in this way I can be sure there is nothing "dirty" in my apache or php or drupal. I followed this [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Drupal)

Everything has gone well at first try until I restored the db. After that.. ERROR 500 again!

Comment: A couple things to check. See if your settings.php file has the correct DB name, location, username, and password. Also, is this in a subdirectory? If so, that still doesn't really explain the 500 error, but it might be something to look into. If this is in a subdirectory you'll likely need to modify .htaccess to reflect that. EDIT: After rereading your problem, I actually kinda doubt this will work since you're still trying to access the same database regardless. Still, check into those things and see if you can find any discrepancies.

Comment: One more note here if my above suggestions don't yield anything. Don't enable all the modules once you have the site copied over. Let that just be part of what happens when you import the database. Simply copy your site's files to localhost (which is where it sounds like you're having the issue). Then you can either manually import the db or activate only Backup & Migrate and import that way, but don't worry about activating the other modules. That activating/deactivation data is stored in the database anyway.